Prove that $ \lim _{u \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x=0 $ without using the Riemann-Lebesgue

Suppose that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)| \mathrm{d} x$ exists. Define

$$
F(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
Prove that:(1) $F(u)$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$
and that (2)$F(u) \rightarrow 0$ as $u \rightarrow+\infty$.
"I'm stuck on the second part of the problem. I'm required not to use the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma here. I think it can be done without it, maybe by using the result from part (1), but I'm not sure how to proceed. Below is my solution using the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, but I'd like to use more analytical methods if possible。
My try: prove that $F(u) \rightarrow 0$ as $u \rightarrow+\infty$.
Since $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)| \mathrm{d} x$ converges, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a positive number $A>0$ such that
$$
\int_{|x|>A}|f(x)| \mathrm{d} x<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
Then, we divide $F(u)$ into two parts to estimate it:
$$
F(u)=\int_{|x| \leq A} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x+\int_{|x|>A} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
Note that
$$
\left|\int_{|x|>A} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x\right| \leq \int_{|x|>A}|f(x)| \mathrm{d} x<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
For the part where $|x| \leq A$, using an idea from the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, due to the rapid oscillation of $\cos (u x)$ over $x \in[-A, A]$, as $u \rightarrow+\infty$,
$$
\int_{|x| \leq A} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x \rightarrow 0
$$
Therefore, there exists $u_0>0$ such that for $u>u_0$,
$$
\left|\int_{|x| \leq A} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
Combining these two estimates, for $u>u_0$, we have
$$
|F(u)| \leq\left|\int_{|x| \leq A} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x\right|+\left|\int_{|x|>A} f(x) \cos (u x) \mathrm{d} x\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon
$$
Thus, as $u \rightarrow+\infty, F(u) \rightarrow 0$.

Point 2 is EXACTLY the Riemann--Lebesgue lemma. This exercise is asking you to prove it.

@GiuseppeNegro，I encounter the problem when in the indefinite parameter-dependence integral chapter,so  I am curious about if we can use some tech-process to get it without using or proving R-L lemma.

I don't really understand what you are talking about. What is the statement of RL lemma, according to you? To me, it is exactly point 2. Your proof is also almost complete: the only missing point is how to show that the integral on $[-A, A]$ tends to zero. You mumbled something about this being "an idea from the RL lemma". If you could make this idea explicit, that would be the end of the proof.

I agree with Giuseppe.  This is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.  The reason you want to prove it without using the R-L lemma is that it would then be a proof of the R-L lemma.
